# Compiling CLFS on Debian 11

Tags: linux

While I fallow the http://clfs.org/view/clfs-sysroot/arm/cross-tools/gmp.html book I get a problem with gmp-6.2.1 configure:

```
error: C++ compiler not available, see config.log for details library. When I invoke the ./configure script
```

I got gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) on my os. Where to search the problem?

```
bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release
/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/dash
ERROR: /bin/sh does not point to bash
Binutils: (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2
./version-check.sh: line 11: bison: command not found
yacc not found
bzip2,  Version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019.
Coreutils:  8.32
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.7
find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0
./version-check.sh: line 25: gawk: command not found
/usr/bin/awk -> /usr/bin/mawk
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
(Debian GLIBC 2.31-13) 2.31
grep (GNU grep) 3.6
gzip 1.10
Linux version 5.10.0-8-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03)
./version-check.sh: line 41: m4: command not found
GNU Make 4.3
GNU patch 2.7.6
Perl version='5.32.1';
sed (GNU sed) 4.7
tar (GNU tar) 1.34
./version-check.sh: line 47: makeinfo: command not found
xz (XZ Utils) 5.2.5
g++ compilation OK
./version-check.sh: line 55: EOF: command not found
```

Comment: Seems you are reading an ancient CLFS text, but using contemporary software. Please run the LFS `version-check-8.2.sh` https://drive.google.com/file/d/10I8bwLR41R3-t440Hu9v_ldBEW19sutx/view?usp=sharing ..... I'd guess you at least missed this: `# apt install g++`

Comment: I edit the post with output as you suggest. Also I create sym link for gcc cpp c++ cxx point to my gcc compilator. I thinking about change debian to 10 version becouse I cant create any new users or group and iven I cat install proper utilits - addusr addgroup. Are they obsolite ? - OFFTOP

Comment: Missing : `sudo apt install bison gawk m4 texinfo` . ....... To be edited : `cd /bin/ && sudo rm -f sh && sudo ln -s bash sh` ........ Please note that g++ cannot be a symlink to gcc, and cpp cannot be linked or changed.

Comment: Thanks for quick respond. I run yours command but It wont solve my problem. I can upload all log file If it can healp.

Comment: Part 2 of the first comment : You cannot access admin commands in ///sbin/ with `su` ..... Is now `su -` , i.e. su<space>hyphen. ........  About adduser, addgroup : `/usr/sbin/{userad, groupadd, adduser, addgroup}`

Comment: Here is all config.log https://pastebin.com/H6vn2q8J

Comment: ?Could be you have linked gcc and g++ together? Very strange config.log . Anyway remove all home made "gcc links" in `/usr/bin/` ......... My Debian 11 gmp log https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wbz5v31JOdAHqx6yHUhlZcKsZZLzu4oz/view?usp=sharing ................ Please do `# apt install --reinstall gcc-10 g++-10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing gcc-cpp for debian
apt install g++
solved the problem.